# Pandas - Take value n month before

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

I am working with datetime. Is there anyway to get a value of n months before.

For example, the data look like:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(100, 1),
    columns=["A"],
    index=pd.date_range("20130101", periods=100, freq="M"),
)

dft
```

Then:

- For every Jul of each year, we take value of December in previous year **and apply it to June next year**
- <s>For other month left (from Aug this year to June next year), we take value of previous month</s>
- **For example: that value from Jul-2000 to June-2001 will be the same and equal to value of Dec-1999.**

What I've been trying to do is:

```
dft['B'] = np.where(dft.index.month == 7, 
                    dft['A'].shift(7, freq='M') ,
                    dft['A'].shift(1, freq='M'))
```

However, the result is simply a copy of column A. I don't know why. But when I tried for single line of code :

```
dft['C'] = dft['A'].shift(7, freq='M')
```

then everything is shifted as expected. I don't know what is the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is index alignment. This shift that you performed acts on the **index**, but using `numpy.where` you convert to arrays **and lose the index**.

Use pandas' [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) instead, everything will remain as Series and the index will be preserved:

```
dft['B'] = (dft['A'].shift(1, freq='M')
            .mask(dft.index.month == 7,  dft['A'].shift(7, freq='M'))
            )
```

output:

```
                   A         B
2013-01-31 -2.202668       NaN
2013-02-28  0.878792 -2.202668
2013-03-31 -0.982540  0.878792
2013-04-30  0.119029 -0.982540
2013-05-31 -0.119644  0.119029
2013-06-30 -1.038124 -0.119644
2013-07-31  0.177794 -1.038124
2013-08-31  0.206593 -2.202668  <- correct
2013-09-30  0.188426  0.206593
2013-10-31  0.764086  0.188426
...              ...       ...
2020-12-31  1.382249 -1.413214
2021-01-31 -0.303696  1.382249
2021-02-28 -1.622287 -0.303696
2021-03-31 -0.763898 -1.622287
2021-04-30  0.420844 -0.763898

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```